# How do disable auto add <br> end of every element in CKEditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor, phpbb

I am using ckeditor in phpbb. when adding content in my post page. I am getting break tag between every line which look my page content odd.how can we disable the `<br/>` tag in ckeditor ?

```
updated my question
```

i have given CKEDITOR.ENTER_P in config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:

    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
    config.toolbar_Basic =
[
    ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']
];

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, break tag is standard mechanism for enters. If you wan't to remove it, try clean your content before save to database str_replace('
', '', $content);

Answer (score 4):

In the config of ckeditor (config.js) you can define which tag will be inserted on ENTER. Mostly users switch between `<br>` or `<p>`, but you can also leave the configuration value empty over there.

Some information from the manual: [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode).

Answer (score 0):

you can set other behaviors to it :

```
CKEDITOR.ENTER_P (1) – new <p> paragraphs are created;
CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR (2) – lines are broken with <br> elements;
CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV (3) – new <div> blocks are created.
```